# Ignore child nodes in XSLT template using mode

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm transforming an XML document into an HTML file for online display (as an electronic book).

Each chapter in the XML file is contained within a `<div>` and has a heading (`<head>`). I need to display each heading twice - once as part of a table of contents at the start, the second time at the top of each chapter. I've used `mode="toc"` within `<xsl:template>` to do this.

My problem is that a few of my `<head>` headings have a child element `<note>`, which contain editorial footnotes. I need these `<note>` tags to be processed when the headings appear at the top of the chapters, but I don't want them to show in the table of contents (i.e. when `mode="toc"`.

My question is how to tell the stylesheet to process `<head>` elements for the table of contents, but ignore any child elements (should they occur)?

Here's an example heading without a note, which displays fine in table of contents mode:

```
<div xml:id="d1.c1" type="chapter">
  <head>Pursuit of pleasure. Limits set to it by Virtue—
  Asceticism is Vice</head>
  <p>Contents of chapter 1 go here</p>
</div>
```

And here's one with a note, which I would want to be stripped out when generating the table of contents:

```
<div xml:id="d1.c6" type="chapter">
  <head>Happiness and Virtue, how diminished by Asceticism in an indirect
  way.—Useful and genuine obligations elbowed out by spurious ones<note
  xml:id="d1.c6fn1" type="editor">In the text, the author has noted at this 
  point: 'These topics must have been handled elsewhere: perhaps gone through 
  with. Yet what follows may serve for an Introduction.'</note></head>
  <p>Contents of chapter 6 go here</p>
</div>
```

My XSL currently looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:head" mode="toc">
    <xsl:if test="../@type = 'chapter'">
        <h3><a href="#{../@xml:id}"><xsl:apply-templates/></a></h3>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I've tried adding a new blank template match in `toc` mode for note, but to no avail. For example:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:note" mode="toc"/>
```

I've also tried `tei:head/tei:note` and `\\tei:head\tei:note`

In my template which matches the whole document (`/`), I use the following to display the table of contents:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:head" mode="toc"/>
```

I've tried adding the following, but to no avail:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:head/tei:note[@type = 'editorial']"
mode="toc"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

p.s. This is my first ever post on SE, so if I have missed out important details please let me know and I'll clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us your full XSLT (if it's not too large) and a sample input and output XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will typically need to pass the mode along when doing the toc-specific processing:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:head" mode="toc" />
<xsl:template match="tei:head[../@type = 'chapter']" mode="toc">
  <h3><a href="#{../@xml:id}"><xsl:apply-templates mode="toc" /></a></h3>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the `mode` attribute on the `xsl:apply-templates`. If you do that, then your template for `tei:note` should be obeyed.

If you're using an identity template, this will probably mean you will need one for the `toc` mode.

Alternatively, if you don't really need mode-specific processing once you've reached `tei:head`, you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:head" mode="toc" />
<xsl:template match="tei:head[../@type = 'chapter']" mode="toc">
  <h3><a href="#{../@xml:id}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::tei:note)]" />
  </a></h3>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. Once I added `mode="toc"` to `xsl:apply-templates` as your example described the later empty `<xsl:template match="tei:note" mode="toc"/>` made the <note> element mute. 

Fantastic!